# Building a similar App like telegram in react native

Tags: react-native, telegram

I am new to react native.
Can we built an app on the top of telegram using react native. app will use API's of telegram.
Please suggest your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can built your frontend app with RN and connect it to telegram servers with telegram APIs. I hope i understand your question correctly.

Comment: Could you refer some links ?

Comment: https://appendto.com/2017/11/build-simple-chat-app-react-native-firebase/ .   https://github.com/jevakallio/react-native-chat-tutorial . https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Ot5LSGHLyY .  i did not do that myself and telegram is not developed with react native. you have to make your UI and just call APIs from telegram. hope this links will help you :-)